# How to write regex for xpath in scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and using it to find a question and answers on a web page. I started the following with this [page](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)

I tried with the selector in this way by observing their xpaths :

```
sel = Selector(text=response.body)
spanList = (sel.xpath('//a/span').extract())
```

but I am getting some duplicate content when doing this, i am getting output in this way

```
"<span>How do I access my account online at Citibank Online?</span>",
"<span>What are the guidelines for creating an internet password?</span>",
"<span>I forgot my User ID for accessing my account online. How do I access my account online now?</span>",
"<span>How do I transfer funds to another bank account in India?</span>",
"<span>How do I transfer funds to my Rupee Checking Account from overseas?</span>",
"<span>How do I transfer funds from my Rupee Checking Account to my local bank account overseas?</span>",
"<span>How do I update my contact information?</span>",
"<span>I have not operated my Rupee Checking Account for a long time and I plan to visit India. Can I transact on my account when I visit India?</span>",
"<span>My Term Deposits with Citibank are due to mature soon. What do I need to do?</span>",
"<span>I would like to terminate my Term Deposits before maturity? Will I lose any money?</span>",
"<span>Why do I need to provide \"Customer Profile Update\" forms so often?</span>",
"<span>How do I access my account online at Citibank Online?</span>",
"<span>What are the guidelines for creating an internet password?</span>",
"<span>I forgot my User ID for accessing my account online. How do I access my account online now?</span>",
..................
```

if you observe the part of output I posted, there first and third spans repeated again.

Is there any way to write a good regex that fetches content without repetition.

sample xpaths of questions from the page i mentioned are

> /html/body/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/div[3]/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/a/span
>
> /html/body/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/div[5]/div[5]/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/a/span
>
> /html/body/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/div[5]/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/div[1](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)/a/span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this,

```
points = response.xpath('//*[@class="ClsInnerDrop"]//span/text()').extract()
pointes = set(points)
```

Comment: it is not preserving the order of output, how can I preserve the order during fetch?

Comment: scrapy is asynchronous. It wont work sequentially. You have add some kind of salt while scraping and need to remove while processing.

Comment: @Satyaaditya set might be causing that write your own algo which can work exact as set without loosing order of elements

Comment: yeah, set is the culprit in my algo even, i changed that. 
Is there any method in scrapy which return nodes instead of text?  I tried removing text and its returnng string with tags

Comment: @Satyaaditya M not getting what exactly you want